# Javascript - How to use the visibility API when you maximise another application

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, visibility

Currently I'm using the visibility API in JavaScript inside a Chrome extension to check how much time someone spends on any given page and then save that data into a database.

However, while testing around I have noticed that the visibility API works when I switch tabs/minimize the chrome window, but not when I maximize another application from my toolbar, the conditional that prints out the seconds passed on a site still keeps going on even though the window itself isn't visible.

Is there a way to bypass that?

My code sample:

```
var that = this;
var tiktok = setInterval(function() {
    if(document.hidden == false){
        that.time++;
        //console.log(that.time);
}}, 1000);
```

Comment: May be use `new Date().getTime()` and compare it to var? https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp

Comment: https://github.com/soixantecircuits/idle-js this is what you want ?

Comment: @l2aelba would prefer a more standard solution, but that script seems to be handy for other projects, thanks.